# difference between string name and string name() in c language

Tags: c, string

I have a hard time understanding what is the difference between

```
 string name;
```

and

```
 string name();
```

Could someone explain me the difference?

Comment: What is the difference between a cat and a car? The words are spelled almost the same, so they must be similar, right? Note: do not use the identifier `string` in C, it will confuse anyone familiar with C++. Do not use empty parenthesis declarations in C, it is obsolete style.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `string` is a data type you have already declared, `string name;` declares the *variable* `name` of type `string`.

The declaration `string name();` declares the *function* `name` that returns a value of type `string`.

A *variable* is a place in memory where the program can store some data. A *function* is a piece of code that can be executed multiple times, when needed; it can receive (zero or more) arguments and it can optionally return one value.

Comment: As a complement, `string name();` in C declares a function that can accept arbitrary parameters (empty parameter list...)

Comment: Notably, `string name();` is obsolete function declaration style and should not be used in C. See 6.11.6.

Answer (score 0):

**string name;**
Declare the string data type variable 'name' in a memory 
where as 
**string name();**
shows the function prototype named as 'name' which returns the string value.